ReactJS: updating the state of arrays in ReactJS, the question has nothing to do with objects
I am trying to add an item to an array in ReactJS code, but the new item (greetings) does not add to the array, what would be the potential error in the blow code?
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // an  array of items
  const [tags, setTags] = useState(["happy", "cheers", "wonderful"]);
  
  const handleClick = () => {   
    console.log("before adding an item");
    console.log(tags);
    setTags([...tags, "greetings"]);
    console.log("after adding an item");
    console.log(tags);    
  };

  return (
    <div>      
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Add an item to the array
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}



Why has my question been marked as closed, the attached similar answer does not belong to my question, and it is a bit more complicated code which I do not understand. I am a newbie to ReactJS and need a simple answer to my question rather than attaching a thread of a more advanced question

The question was closed as a duplicate because the linked question already answers it in detail.  The problem is not that state isn't being updated, it's that you're not effectively observing that update.  tags won't change until the component re-renders.  You can observe the update by using tags in the component (which the code shown currently doesn't do).  Or by adding a useEffect which includes tags in its dependency array and outputs tags.  Or even just outputting tags in the component body.

ok, I got it, but useEffect is an advanced topic yet, I got what you have explained, thank you.

React state updates using useState are asynchronous. This means that when you call setTags, it schedules an update to the state, but does not immediately execute it. Therefore, when you log the state of tags right after calling setTags, it hasn't been updated yet.
Solution:
To observe the updated state, you can console.log tags out of the handleClick function
